# Basic buffer overflow able to overwrite EIP but doesn't correctly overwrite when using memory address

Tags: linux, penetration-test

I wrote a basic vulnerable app in C.

#include

```
void vuln(char *arg) {
    char buffer[10];
    strcpy(buffer, arg);
}  

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    vuln(argv[1]);
    return 0; 
}
```

I determined that if I input 26 characters, characters 23-26 will overwrite EIP. I can successfully represent this in gdb. When try to replace some arbitrary character with my desired address (the address to system() in libc 0xb7e41b40 on my machine) eip becomes gibberish. The input ends up being "a * 22 \x40\x1b\xe4\xb7" why is that? I pasted the gdb output below as well. Thank you.

```
    (gdb) run $(python -c 'print ("\x41" * 22) + "\x40" + "\x1b\xeb\xb7"')
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/bob/Documents/C/Disassembler_Fun/overflow $(python -c 'print ("\x41" * 22) + "\x40" + "\x1b\xeb\xb7"')

Breakpoint 1, 0x004005f4 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff364) at overflow.c:9
9       vuln(argv[1]);
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7eb1b4b in __strftime_internal (s=<optimized out>, 
    maxsize=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x414140b9>, format=<optimized out>, 
    tp=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x41414149>, 
    tzset_called=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x4141414d>, 
    loc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x41414151>) at strftime_l.c:920
920 strftime_l.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb) run $(python -c 'print ("\x41" * 22) + "\x40\x1b\xeb\xb7"')
Starting program: /home/mj/Documents/C/Disassembler_Fun/overflow $(python -c 'print ("\x41" * 22) + "\x40\x1b\xeb\xb7"')

Breakpoint 1, 0x004005f4 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff364) at overflow.c:9
9       vuln(argv[1]);
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7eb1b4b in __strftime_internal (s=<optimized out>, 
    maxsize=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x414140b9>, format=<optimized out>, 
    tp=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x41414149>, 
    tzset_called=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x4141414d>, 
    loc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x41414151>) at strftime_l.c:920
920 strftime_l.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) i r eip
eip            0xb7eb1b4b   0xb7eb1b4b <__strftime_internal+5227>
(gdb)
```

Why is the last byte changing from 0 to b? it should be 0xb7eb1b40 not 0xb7eb1b4b

Comment: Look closely - that isn't gibberish. b7e41b40 looks a lot like 401be4b7 ...